# wlan0 device missing

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I can't seem to get my wifi working and I feel i've exhausted google's search capabilities.

Here is the output of `lspci` for the device

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2123]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
    Region 0: Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <2us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [13c v1] Device Serial Number 24-0a-00-ff-ff-00-00-01
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [1b0 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 71680ns
        Max no snoop latency: 71680ns
    Capabilities: [220 v1] #15
```

As you can see, there is no `kernel driver` associated with it, and I have no idea how to get one associated with it. I'm using debian 7.8. I know that the correct kernel driver for it is the wl module, which I have installed but for some reason it doesn't associate with that network card.

here is modprobe debug output:

```
root@void:~# modprobe -vvv wl
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:519 kmod_module_new_from_lookup: input alias=wl, normalized=wl
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:525 kmod_module_new_from_lookup: lookup modules.dep wl
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:542 kmod_search_moddep: use mmaped index 'modules.dep' modname=wl
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='wl' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:398 kmod_pool_add_module: add 0x7fbb30aef4a0 key='wl'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='lib80211' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='lib80211' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:398 kmod_pool_add_module: add 0x7fbb30aef600 key='lib80211'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:178 kmod_module_parse_depline: add dep: /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='cfg80211' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='cfg80211' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:398 kmod_pool_add_module: add 0x7fbb30af2e20 key='cfg80211'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:178 kmod_module_parse_depline: add dep: /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='rfkill' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='rfkill' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:398 kmod_pool_add_module: add 0x7fbb30af2f80 key='rfkill'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:178 kmod_module_parse_depline: add dep: /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/net/rfkill/rfkill.ko
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:184 kmod_module_parse_depline: 3 dependencies for wl
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:546 kmod_module_new_from_lookup: lookup wl=0, list=0x7fbb30aef5a0
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:435 kmod_module_unref: kmod_module 0x7fbb30aef4a0 released
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:406 kmod_pool_del_module: del 0x7fbb30aef4a0 key='wl'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:435 kmod_module_unref: kmod_module 0x7fbb30af2f80 released
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:406 kmod_pool_del_module: del 0x7fbb30af2f80 key='rfkill'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:435 kmod_module_unref: kmod_module 0x7fbb30af2e20 released
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:406 kmod_pool_del_module: del 0x7fbb30af2e20 key='cfg80211'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:435 kmod_module_unref: kmod_module 0x7fbb30aef600 released
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:406 kmod_pool_del_module: del 0x7fbb30aef600 key='lib80211'
libkmod: INFO ../libkmod/libkmod.c:319 kmod_unref: context 0x7fbb30aef220 released
```

Is there something like `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/modules.alias` that I'm supposed to update?

EDIT TO ADD:

```
root@void:~# lsmod | grep -i wl
wl                   2552134  0 
iwlwifi               166761  0 
mac80211              192806  1 iwlwifi
lib80211               12941  1 wl
cfg80211              137243  3 mac80211,iwlwifi,wl


oot@void:~# dmesg | grep -i net
[    0.003674] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.921992] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    1.075822] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.078897] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.237519] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    1.407312] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.407547] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.408255] Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.426190] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
[    1.608316] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    3.220683] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   10.365781] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   10.390360] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   10.541140] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[   11.474762] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   13.015205] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

root@void:~# dmesg | grep -i wl
[    9.846040] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.

root@void:~# dmesg | grep cfg80211
[    9.835597] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain

root@void:~# dmesg | grep -i addr
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x08] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 8, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[   11.474762] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   13.015205] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

---

```
paul@void:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf 
# wl module from Broadcom conflicts with the following modules:
blacklist b44
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b43
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb
```

Comment: Hmmm interesting development... they are already blacklisted... Try the Arch Route, and let me know the outcome.  Also, probably a stupid question, but you are using a `dkms` enabled kernel, right?

Answer (score 2):

I hate to tell you this, but this card is not supported, by the default driver.  Under normal circumstances, all Broadcom cards are supported by the [b43/b43legacy drivers on the Linux Wireless Project](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43), but as you can see on the Supported Hardware list, the entry for `14e4:43b1` shows:

```
+================================================+
| ID     Support Name    Modes      PHY Alternate|
+================================================+
| 14e4:43b1 no  BCM4352 a/b/g/n/ac  AC (r3) wl   |                                             |                                                |
+================================================+
```

The **Alternate Driver** is listed as **wl**, which you've found also.  Reading:

[AskUbuntu Post - How can I install Broadcom Wireless Adapter BCM4352 802.11ac PCID [14e4:43b1] (rev 03) on fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590442/how-can-i-install-broadcom-wireless-adapter-bcm4352-802-11ac-pcid-14e443b1-r).  The driver is no longer listed on the Linux Wireless Project Page, so that's as close as I can get you, but that should start you on the right path.  Have you tried the `modprobe` listed in the answer?

---

Since Ubuntu is a Debian derivative, you should be able to try the apt install listed in chilli555's answer.  If this works, you're in luck

---

### Example Outputs After Dmesg Requests

```
dmesg | grep ath
[   17.501212] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   17.501213] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   17.501214] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[   17.501215] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[   17.501215] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[   17.795746] ath9k 0000:01:07.0 wlp1s7: renamed from wlan0

dmesg | grep cfg80211
[   17.659629] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CN
[   17.662311] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: CN
[   17.662314] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   17.662315] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   17.662317] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   17.662319] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (N/A)
[   17.662320] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[   17.662322] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[   17.662323] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 59400000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 2800 mBm), (N/A)
[   17.662324] cfg80211:   (59400000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4400 mBm), (N/A)
[   17.662325] cfg80211:   (63720000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 2800 mBm), (N/A)
```

---

Interesting thought: The map search yielded CN - China, but I live in the USA.  HMMM.

Since your output has no frequency ranges listed, I wonder if we need to blacklist a module??  Read the Troubleshooting section in The [Broadcom Wireless Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl), and then try [Blacklisting](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting) the b43, and the ssb driver, along with the bcma and bcrm80211(>=kernel-3.3.1) drivers, and lastly, does this card work on Arch?  Fire up a LiveCD, and see if tools like ping work after booting... If it works in Arch, but not in Debian, then Debian is misconfigured, but if it works in neither chances are you've got a wonky or unsupported chipset.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the debian equivalent of that module but it still doesn't work, is there any way I can dive deeper into the problem to check what the `wl` module I downloaded supports or how I associate it with my device?

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep wl` return? Also `dmesg | grep net`?

Comment: Edited to add the lsmod output, the dmesg grep prints nothing

Comment: From your `lsmod` output the driver is loading, but driver wl is being used by 0 items.  What's the output of `dmesg | grep wl` and  `dmesg | grep cfg80211` and dmesg | grep addr`?  Also, have you tried `depmod -a` and a reboot?

Comment: sorry my dmesg was full of useless UFW output, I restarted and have edited my answer with the output of the previous and all of the above dmesg outputs.

Comment: See Example Output Above.  The Driver is different but the idea is the same.

Comment: The package I installed already installed a blacklist in `/etc/modprobe.d/` - I've printed it above. Also tried a depmod -a and restart but the same.

Comment: OK, I've got to be somewhere, but I'll be back later tonight and check in.  Try another distribution's LiveCD to rule out Debian as the cause.  Doesn't have to be Arch, I just used their Wiki.  If you want to stay within the Debian family try Ubuntu or Mint